# How to handle two Mouses on same device seperately?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have Qt5.10, cross compiled for Raspberry Pi3

I have a QML based program where I capture the mouse wheel events and execute some functions!

I want to connect another mouse to my Raspberry Pi. So each Mouse will have a different function in my program!!

How to differentiate between this two mouse devices?

Can I get each Mouse ID for example and act accordingly?

Comment: Aren't you limited by the OS itself?

Comment: I don't know, therotically it is just an input device so I think I can!!

Comment: Can you make two pointers visible on the screen (regardless of your app)?

Comment: If I connect two Mice, I can see them and they act at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`MultiPointTouchArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html) you can handle your 2 mice as separate `touchPoints`.

However you will be limited in the actions you can handle. But playing with the `pressed`, `released` and `touchUpdated` signals, you can easily handle click/drag events:

```
MultiPointTouchArea {

    mouseEnabled: true

    touchPoints: [
        // your 2 recognizable touchPoints for your 2 mice
        TouchPoint { id: point1 },
        TouchPoint { id: point2 }
    ]

    onPressed: {
        touchPoints.forEach(function(touchPoint) {
            if (touchPoint === point1) {
                console.log("FIRST MOUSE PRESSED:", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)
            } else if (touchPoint === point2){
                console.log("SECOND MOUSE PRESSED:", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)
            }
        })
    }

    onReleased: {
        touchPoints.forEach(function(touchPoint) {
            if (touchPoint === point1) {
                console.log("FIRST MOUSE RELEASED:", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)
            } else if (touchPoint === point2){
                console.log("SECOND MOUSE RELEASED:", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)
            }
        })
    }

    onTouchUpdated: {
        touchPoints.forEach(function(touchPoint) {
            if (touchPoint === point1) {
                console.log("FIRST MOUSE UPDATED:", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)
            } else if (touchPoint === point2){
                console.log("SECOND MOUSE UPDATED:", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

output (tested only with a single mouse, but it should work with 2):

```
qml: FIRST MOUSE PRESSED: 418 326
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 419 327
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 420 327
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 421 327
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 422 328
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 423 328
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 424 329
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 425 329
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 426 329
qml: FIRST MOUSE UPDATED: 427 329
qml: FIRST MOUSE RELEASED: 427 329
```

Unfortunately I can not think of another solution able to catch multiple hovered/wheel events.